# Laravel JSON Response with Eloquent

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, eloquent

I got three tables called threads,posts,users

threads got

```
id
title
etc.
```

posts got

```
id
thread_id
user_id
post
post_date
etc.
```

users got

```
id
username 
password
email
etc.
```

when users wants to view a thread i simply call a jquery ajax request using post data to send thread id and return this code :

```
Response::eloquent(Thread::find(Input::get('threadid'))->posts()->get());
```

this code does his job perfectly and return posts by same thread_id. (post model also eager loads the user by looking user_id).

however this code grabs every attribute of posts and users i mean everything to json, post_date, post_updatereason, user_password, user_email all columns in tables.

I just want to grab post, username and post_date with json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `public static $hidden = array('list', 'of', 'fields');` to your model which extends Eloquent. Then none of the fields which you enumarate in the array will be returned. For more information [refer to the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#to-array).

For example

```
class User extends Eloquent {
  public static $hidden = array('password', 'email');
}
```

will return the user model without the `password` and `email`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using laravel 3, and this is probably the same for version 4, you should be able to specific the columns you want using the get method.

```
Response::eloquent(Thread::find(Input::get('threadid'))->posts()->get(['username','post_date']));
```

Comment: I did that actualy but if I not grab user_id model can't find the author(which eager loads in Post::with('author')). If i put user_id in get() json will show the user_id